# NGINX SEO Rewrite Rules Get 504 Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: php, apache, nginx, url-rewriting

Recently I am move my website Apache to Nginx.

I am trying to setup rewrite rule for SEO URL in my nginx server.

i am setup following rule that redirect page but web page load multiple time so my nginx get 504 Gateway Timeout Error

SO how I can fix this error.

Following are rewrite rules any help ?

## Apache Rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_q_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

## Nginx Rule

```
rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_q_=$1 break;
```

## Default File

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_q_=$1 break;

    server_name _;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


}
```